# making a ui-sref functionality in a .js

Tags: angularjs

**Setting:**
I have an angular app.

**What I have:**

I have this: `ui-sref="providerDetail({id:provider.id})"` functioning.

It is a functioning link to a page giving details on a given provider.

**What I want:**

I have a button that submits a form and makes a new provider. This works. But I also want this button to forward the user to that new provider's detail page.

I have a function running that prints the id of the new provider to the console when it is made, I just can't figure out how to forward the user to the appropirate location.

**Note:**

I can add this to the function:

```
window.location = "/dashboard.html#!/providerDetail/" +id;
```

And it will take me to the new page, but I get this impression that this is a bad route to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't manually change the URL in AngularJS application, do it in Angular way so that you don't need to worry about manually kick of digest cycle. From function you could call `$state.go` method to navigate between states.

```
function myFunction(id) {
    $state.go('providerDetail', { id: id})
}
```

> **Note:** Please make sure you inject `$state` inside you controller.